# Android recycle view like a gallery view?

Tags: java, android, view, android-gallery, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to create a recycleview that works exactly like a Gallery view where when you are scrolling horizontally it will lock the current viewed item centraly like in a gallery view?

Is this possible?

So far I have created my recycleView and used a LinearLayoutManager set as Horizontal in order for it to scroll horizonally(works fine) but how do I lock the current item like in a gallery view?

```
   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyMapAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecyclerView provides these built-in layout managers:

- LinearLayoutManager shows items in a vertical or horizontal scrolling list.
- GridLayoutManager shows items in a grid.
- StaggeredGridLayoutManager shows items in a staggered grid.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView

GridLayoutManager:

```
    GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4); // (Context context, int spanCount)
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

StaggeredGridLayoutManager:

```
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL); // (int spanCount, int orientation)
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though.  Neither of those LayoutManagers behave like a Gallery view.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And this is what I did, I added an OnScrollListener to my RecyclerView:

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(getScrolledPosition());
                galleryAdapter.highlightItem(getMidPosition());
            } 
        }
```

and scrollToPosition method looks like this:

```
    private int getScrolledPosition() {

    return (int) ((double) recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset() / (double) galleryAdapter.getItemWidth());
}
```

getMidPosition:

```
private int getMidPosition() {
    return getScrolledPosition() + (GalleryAdapter.ITEM_NUM / 2);
}
```

GalleryAdapter is my adpater which extended from RecyclerView.Adapter. In this way I highlighted the central item. The problem is when I drag or fling the recyclerview, the current central item would not be highlighted.It works only if the view stops scrolling.